# Can't create a contract in web3.py

Tags: smartcontracts, web3py

I try to use read functions, for example, to get the balance. There is such a code:

```
import json
from web3 import Web3

rpc = "https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/"
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(rpc))

wallet_address = Web3.to_checksum_address("0xE55bB4c43C4083E567D678C4f7C1AAb522FDBe6A")
contract_address = Web3.to_checksum_address("0xf474cf03cceff28abc65c9cbae594f725c80e12d")
with open("abi.json", encoding="utf-8-sig") as file:
    abi = json.load(file)

contract = web3.eth.contract(contract_address, abi=abi)
balance = contract.functions.balanceOf(wallet_address).call()
print(balance)
```

I'm getting an error:
`web3.exceptions.BadFunctionCallOutput: Could not transact with/call contract function, is contract deployed correctly and chain synced?`

The problem is that I can't get the contract address, I went to testnet bscscan, took a random contract address and pasted it into this variable, but I end up with a wallet balance of 0, even though it has 0.1 BNB on it on Testnet. When I get the wallet balance via Web3().eth.get_balance(), outputs everything correctly in Wei. Help please!

............................